# How do I get the twitter api trends json data into flash as3?

Tags: json, flash, actionscript-3

So I know how to get json data into flash with twitter's search api because the array names normally aren't weird, but I'm not really too experienced with json. For the trends api data, I'm not sure how to access it because the array name is the date and theres spaces and colons in it, and I'm not really sure what to do. Normally in flash to get the json data I'd do something like

json.trends[0].2012-01-21 01:20.name

but that doesn't work. Can someone tell me how to pull out the name data when the array name is the date. I apologize if I'm calling these things the wrong name, I'm not too sure on what their proper names are.

To get a better understanding of what I'm talking about copy this link https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/daily.json into this site http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ in order to format the JSON.

I hope my question makes sense and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            var result:Object = JSON.decode(urlLoader.data);

            var trends:Object = result.trends;

            // trends in an object here, not array
            // loop to find the properties in trends 
            for(var date:String in trends){
                // date is a property of trends 
                // trends[date] is the value of property date
                // trends[date] is an array
                var items:Array = trends[date];

                //for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                //  var item:Object = items[i];

                // loop in the array to get each item
                for each(var item:Object in items){

                }

            }
```

Comment: You are forever my hero yet again, haha, it works perfectly, thank you! My question is how did you know doing this would grab the dates [for(var date:String in trends)] I didn't even think of the actual date in the JSON data being a string. Do you think you could give me and explanation of what's being done in your code minus the trace statements, I'd like to understand it better, thanks again!    for(var date:String in trends){

                var items:Array = trends[date];

                for each(var item:Object in items){
                  
                }

            }

Comment: `for(var property:String in object){ trace(property, object[property]);}` loop is used to get all properties of an object

Answer (score 0):

Try this `json.trends[0]["2012-01-21 01:20"].name`

`x.y` is pretty much just syntactic sugar for `x["y"]`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I just tried your line of code but no luck, that too gets me an error and that error is "A term is undefined and has no properties." Thanks again for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Try `json.trends["2012-01-21 01:20"][0].name`

`trends` is not an array.

Also, you would have to look out for that the time value (that gives an array) will change over time.

I wonder why twitter has chosen this kind of odd structure, where you would have to somehow look up the date and time used in the data, rather than accessing the array the same way on each call? If someone knows or can guess why, please tell in a comment.

```
{
   "trends":{
      "2012-01-21 10:40":[
         {
            "name":"#IReallyLike",
            "query":"#IReallyLike",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "events":null
         },
         {
            "name":"SOPA Is Dead",
            "query":"\"SOPA Is Dead\"" ...
```

Comment: Yeah, if they used something like "date" that would probably make my life easier, and thank you for trying to help but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: json.trends["2012-01-21 01:20"][0].name works, provided you replace "2012-01-21 01:20" with the right string. I have tested that, so I know it works. If it still doesn't work for you, something else is wrong.